# How can I get javascript to choose a random option from various choices?

Tags: javascript, random, greasemonkey

I would like a program in grease-monkey to replace swear words with the names of famous poets. The program should do this randomly.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Profanity Filter - Quantum Remix
// @namespace     kornk/skidfilter
// @description Filters words 
// @include         *
// ==/UserScript==

/*

  Author: MCE - Edited by aaa


 Version: 1.0
 1.0 - First Release

 Competing scripts and extensions:
 * http://www.arantius.com/article/arantius/clean+language/

  Improvements Needed:


   */

  // Licensed for unlimited modification and redistribution as long as
  // this notice is kept intact.

 (function() {

//some performance settings
var MillisecondsPauseBetweenBatches=3;
var NodesPerBatch = 20;
var ReplacementText = "TBD";

//edit the words here
//sorted alpha backwords to catch bad word groupings
var badwords=['shit', 'fuck', 'cunt', 'dick', 'dicks', 'penis', 'vagina', 'whore', 'fromatic', 'ass', 'asses', 'shits', 'fucks', 'fucker', 'fuckers', 'motherfucker', 'motherfuck', 'motherfucking', 'fucking', 'motherfuckers', 'nigger', 'niggers', 'gay', 'gays', 'homo', 'homos', 'vaginas', 'pussy', 'whores', 'shits', 'shitter', 'anus', 'arse', 'arsehole', 'asshat', 'ass-hat', 'assbag', 'douche', 'assbite', 'asscock', 'asses', 'assface', 'asshole', 'asshead', 'assnigger', 'assshole', 'asswipe', 'bampot', 'bastard', 'beaner', 'bitch', 'bitchass', 'bitches', 'bitchtits', 'bitchy', 'blow job', 'blowjob', 'bollocks', 'bollox', 'boner', 'bullshit', 'buttplug', 'butt plug', 'buttfucker', 'chink', 'choad', 'chode', 'clit', 'clitface', 'clitfuck', 'cock', 'cockass', 'cockbite', 'cockburger', 'cockface', 'cum', 'cumdumpster', 'cumguzzler', 'cuntface', 'cuntmuffin', 'damn', 'dickbag', 'dickface', 'dickmilk', 'dike', 'dildo', 'doochbag', 'douchebag', 'dumbass', 'dumbshit', 'dyke', 'fag', 'fagbag', 'faggot', 'fuckbag', 'fucker', 'fuckhead', 'fucking', 'fucken', 'fucktard', 'gooch', 'hoe', 'jizz', 'mothafucka', 'mothefuckas', 'mothafucking', 'motherfuckin', 'motherfucken', 'piss', 'queer', 'tit', 'boob', 'twat', 'wanker'];

var i = 0;
var st = new Date().valueOf();  //for performance testing   
var els = document.evaluate('//text()', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var bw="\\b("+badwords.join("|")+")\\b";
bw=new RegExp(bw, "gi");

//do the title first
document.title=document.title.replace(bw, ReplacementText);

function CleanSome() 
{       
    var el;
    var newval="";
    var data = "";
    var loopCount = 0;
    while ((el=els.snapshotItem(i++)) && (loopCount <= NodesPerBatch)) 
    {
        data = el.data;
        newval = data.replace(bw, ReplacementText);
        if (newval.length != data.length ||  newval != data)
        {
            //check the length first since its quicker than a a string comparison.
            //only change the value if we need to. its quicker.
            el.data = newval;
        }
        loopCount++;
    }

    if (el != null)
    {
        //more work left to do
        i--;
        GoNow(MillisecondsPauseBetweenBatches);
    }
    else
    {
        //we're done
        DoneNow();
    }
}

function DoneNow()
{
    var et = new Date().valueOf();
    //alert("Milliseconds to complete: " + (et - st).toString()); //timer code
}

function GoNow(WaitUntil)
{
    window.setTimeout(CleanSome, WaitUntil); 
}

//spin the initial "thread"
GoNow(0);

 })
 ();
```

I would like it to randomly replace one of the swear words with one of the names of these 18 poets,

```
Walt Whitman
Edna St. Vincent Millay
Emily Dickinson
E. E. Cummings
Robert Frost
Nikki Giovanni 
Ralph Waldo Emerson
T.S. Elliot
Edgar Allan Poe
W.B. Yeats
Lord Tennyson
Maya Angelou
Langston Hughes
Sylvia Plath
Elizabeth Bishop
Anne Sexton
Anne Bradstreet
Gwendolyn Elizabeth Brooks
```

Comment: Obscenity filters are normally just such a bad idea. Your filter in particular will be extremely simple to game, in which case, what is the point unless it's just for cuteness factor? http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: I still don't understand why penis is considered as a swear word. I don't think someone will call you a penis if he is angry.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
var text = "hello cruel world, hello",
    goodWords = ["yo","man"],
    badWords = ["hello","world"];
badWords.forEach(function(bad){
  var word = goodWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*goodWords.length)],
      reg = new RegExp(bad,"gi");
  text = text.replace(reg,word);
})
```

How about a [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ipFDB)